# Como são exibidos os textos e conteúdos em WordPress a partir do arquivo PHP?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Estou aprendendo PHP para alterar o site da empresa, hospedado no servidor e já online. Tenho todos os acessos, porém estou acostumado somente com HTML e CSS, e nas pesquisas e tutoriais de iniciante que estudei, ensinam a sintaxe normal de programação(variáveis, loops, etc), porém nao encontrei nada que me explicasse de onde surgem os textos e conteúdos do site em PHP. Segue abaixo um código PHP que me retorna o texto:

> Contamos com um cd equipado com os melhores equipamentos de (...) estoque e organização.

E o código relativo a isso parece ser esse:

```
<div id="content">
            <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
            <?php
            query_posts(
                    array(
                        'post_type' => 'logisticadinamica',
                        'orderby' => 'ID',
                        'posts_per_page' => 1
                    )
            );
            if (have_posts()) {
                while (have_posts()) {
                    the_post();
                    ?>  
                    <?php the_content(); ?> 
                    <?php
                }
            }
            ?>
```

**Não estou pedindo que me ensinem PHP pois seria absurdo**, só gostaria de saber onde se encontra o texto gerado.

Comment: Isso aí é wordpress.

Comment: Exato, o que só piora minha vida de iniciante :'D

Comment: vem do wordpress, você pode aprender melhor aqui https://codex.wordpress.org/ esse texto está vindo da area administrativa do site tente acessar http://exemplo.com.br/wp-admin

Comment: Ah entendi, loguei no wordpress e encontrei os textos lá.

Então, por exemplo, todo o texto abaixo é somente para adicionar uma das abas do menu, em caso de ter algum conteúdo, e se tiver, eu vou encontrar esse conteúdo no wordpress e não em códigos correto?

<?php the_post_thumbnail('logisticaindex', array('title' => get_the_title())); ?>
                    <h3>LOGÍSTICA</h3>
                    <p>
                        <?php resumo(20); ?>
                    </p>
                    <span><a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/logistica/')); ?>">ver mais...</a></span>

            <?php

Comment: Desculpe, não quero criticar, mas como alguma empresa colocar alguém pra alterar o site sem ter o conhecimento minimo da linguagem? Só uma sugestão, não mexa nos códigos nativos do wordpress, pois se fizer isto provavelmente terá muita dor de cabeça. Tenho certeza que vai levar o comentário como uma critica construtiva.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tudo que está dentro das tags de abertura e fechamento do PHP (`<?php ?>`) não vai aparecer no HTML, *a não ser* que o comando PHP seja para *imprimir* alguma coisa.

Não aparece no HTML:

```
<?php $teste = "tal coisa"; ?>
```

Aparece no HTML:

```php
<?php echo $teste; ?>
Isto também aparece pois está fora das tags PHP.
<?php var_dump($teste); /* Este var_dump também aparece, mas este comentário PHP não aparece */ ?>
```

Então, o importante é saber se o comando PHP imprime alguma coisa ou não. Num template WordPress você vai encontrar funções específicas do PHP, tipo [`echo`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.echo.php) e [`var_dump`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.var-dump.php), e outras específicas do WordPress, tipo [`the_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post) e [`the_content`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content).

Enquanto aprende, consulte sempre essas duas fontes para saber o que uma função faz: o manual PHP e o manual WordPress.

O HTML de um site WordPress vai ser gerado a partir dos arquivos do Theme/template que você selecionou. Cada arquivo do theme serve para uma situação específica, por exemplo o `page.php` vai ser usado para mostrar o conteúdo das Páginas (mas não dos Posts/Entradas). Manual: [WordPress › Template Hierarchy | Theme Developer Handbook | WordPress Developer Resources](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/)